# CPU Usage on File Upload with Telerik RadAsyncUpload

Tags: asp.net, iis, telerik, asyncfileupload

I'm having a huge CPU usage when two or more users are uploading files using RadAsyncUpload. We tried to limit the CPU usage at 20% at IIS, but it did'nt solved. One of the cons is that the upload speed sometimes is like 1Kbps :(

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with the ChunkSize property to see if it will help http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload-disable-chunk-upload.html
If large files are used, perhaps they go to the memory and this loads the server.

I have never heard of such a problem before, though.